# I want to create a variable to prevent user repeat click but it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wrote some codes to make a scroll animate,when user click a button,the scrollbar scroll to somewhere smoothly.

I don't want user repeat click the button to make the code run again,so I  create a variable to prevent it,but sadly the code seem clash.

How can I do to make it works correct?

It works for a vue item.It is a global function,I create a js file for this and import in my vue components.

Here is my code:

```
// scrollToisClick is the variable to prevent repeat click
let scrollToisClick = true
export function scrollToAnywhere(location) {
  if (scrollToisClick) {
    let docEl = document.documentElement, top_distance = docEl.scrollTop, scroll_height = docEl.scrollHeight, per_distance = 0, scrollToAnimation, between_distance = Math.abs(location - top_distance)
    // I set it be false
    scrollToisClick = false
    // Get the scrollbar scroll to top or bottom. P.s.It's not necessary
    if (location > top_distance) {
      scrollToAnimation = setInterval(() => {
        per_distance += between_distance / 50
        window.scrollTo(0, top_distance + per_distance)
      }, 20)
      // monitor if user scroll by himself,stop scroll animate
      window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        if (docEl.scrollTop > top_distance + per_distance - 10) {
          clearInterval(scrollToAnimation)
          scrollToAnimation = null
          // I don't know how to remove monitor so I guess it makes the variable be true when the animate already complete
          scrollToisClick = true
          per_distance = null
          top_distance = null
        } else {
          setTimeout(() => {
            clearInterval(scrollToAnimation)
            scrollToAnimation = null
            scrollToisClick = true
            per_distance = null
            top_distance = null
          }, 1000)
        }
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You can pass third argument `once` to button's click listener - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener. Or once the button is clicked disable the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason!It because I set a EventListener and I don't remove it.Here is my revised code:

```
function clear() {
  isClick = true
  clearInterval(scrollToAnimation)
  scrollToAnimation = null
  per_distance = null
  top_distance = null
  per_time = 0
}

function monitorWheel() {
  window.removeEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
  if (docEl.scrollTop == location) {
    clear()
    window.removeEventListener('wheel', monitorWheel)
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      clear()
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', monitorWheel)
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
    }, per_time * 20)
  }
}

function monitorScroll() {
  if (docEl.scrollTop == location) {
    clear()
    window.removeEventListener('wheel', monitorWheel)
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      clear()
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', monitorWheel)
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
    }, per_time * 20)
  }
}
window.addEventListener('wheel', monitorWheel)
window.addEventListener('scroll', monitorScroll)
```

After this modify,when the scroll animate is over,the EventListener will be remove,then  question is solved!